# Making multi-group line plot with many observations more readable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I have created the following plot:

[image: Ugly plot]

From a bigger version (5 rows, 58 columns) of this df:

```
df <- data.frame(row.names = c("ROBERT", "FRANK", "MICHELLE", "KATE"), `1` = c(31, 87, 22, 12), `2` = c(37, 74, 33, 20), `3` = c(35, 32, 44, 14))
colnames(df) <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

In the following manner:

```
df = df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Name") %>% 
  as.data.frame()

df <- melt(df ,  id.vars = 'Name', variable.name = 'ep')
ggplot(df, aes(ep,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = Name, group=Name))
```

The plot kind of shows what I'd like to, but it really is a mess. Does anyone have a suggestion that would help me increasing its readability?
Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: My first thought was faceting, grouping the observations in some logical way. In any case, there's an [interesting discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46334/line-graph-has-too-many-lines-is-there-a-better-solution#46350) of this topic over on the Stats section of stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options for visualizing lots of datapoints across a smallish number of cases. These are illustrated with a subset of the `txhousing` data included with `ggplot2`.

**Solution 1: Faceting**

As @rdelrossi suggested, one solution is to facet by `Name`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(ep,value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = Name, group=Name), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Name), ncol = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Solution 2: Smoothing**

Use `geom_smooth()` to smooth out local fluctuations to see larger longer-term trends:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(ep,value)) + 
  geom_smooth(
    aes(colour = Name, group=Name), 
    se = FALSE,
    span = 1,    # higher number = smoother
    size = 1.25
  ) +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Solution 3: Lasagna**

Sometimes called a "lasagna plot," this is a heatmap with cases on the y axis, time (or whatever) on the x axis, and values mapped to color. It's a different way of comparing changes within (left to right) and between (up and down) individuals.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(ep, Name, colour = value, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(size = .5) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "B", aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]
*(may want to click through to larger image)*

##### *Data prep:*

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- txhousing %>% 
  filter(
    city %in% c("Beaumont", "Amarillo", "Arlington", "Corpus Christi", "El Paso"),
    between(year, 2004, 2012)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  mutate(
    Name = city, 
    value = scale(sales),
    ep = ym(str_c(year, month))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your readability concern is just the `x` axis labels, then I think the main issue is that when you use `reshape2::melt()` the result is that the column `ep` is a `factor` which means that the `x` axis of your plot will show all the levels and get crowded. The solution is to convert it to `numeric` and then it will adjust the labels in a sensible way.

I replace your use of `reshape2::melt()` with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` which has superseded it within the {tidyverse} but your original code would still work.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(`1` = c(31, 87, 22, 12), `2` = c(37, 74, 33, 20), `3` = c(35, 32, 44, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("ROBERT", "FRANK", "MICHELLE", "KATE"))

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Name") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Name, names_to = "ep") %>%
  mutate(ep = as.numeric(ep)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ep, value, color = Name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be the use of a geom_bar()

Sample code:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(fill=Name))  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=ep, y=value, group=Name),stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  labs(x="ep", y="count")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  theme_bw()
```

Plot:

[image]

Also you can add `facet_grid(~Name)+`

[image]

Also you can add

`geom_text(aes(label=value), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))+`

[image]